# c# log file truncation

Tags: c#

I would like to create a class that creates and manages log files. I would like the log file to be truncated when it exceeds a certain amount of text lines. Does any one have any recommendations on best practices to remove lines from the beginning of a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is for a class assignment, why not use available open-source alternatives? Log4net allows you to roll between a specified number of log files.

Comment: and even if you really want to do it, I'm sure Log4Net would be a good place to look for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Don't

The long version

When you reach the limit of lines, create a new log file, keep the previous log file, but remove the one before that.

You are now guarenteed to have at leat n lines of log file at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple Logfile class in C# at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/a-convenient-logfile-class.

However, files are truncated at the end--not the start. So if you truncated the file, you'd keep the old data and lose the new data. That's probably not what you want.

I would recommend either deleting the file every so often, or creating a new one. For example, you can write to a filename based on the current date, or a name based on the date that would change only once a week, etc.